# Loading datastore entities from Python project in Go leads to nested structs slices of slices error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, app-engine-ndb

I am writing a module in my Google AppEngine project in Go for performance reasons but need to be able to read from some of the entities I have in datastore. I wrote out the Go code to be able to read the entities I built out in Python but I am getting the following error:

`datastore: flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices: field "Messages"`

Model Definitions in Python:

```
class ModelB(ndb.Model):
    msg_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    cat_ids = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    list_ids = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    default_list_id_index = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)

class ModelA(ndb.Model):
    date_join = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    owner_salutation = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    owner_email_address = ndb.StringProperty()
    logo_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    ...
    messages = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(ModelB, name='bm', repeated=True)
```

And in Go:

```
type ModelB struct {
    MessageID          string   `datastore:"msg_id,noindex"`
    CategoryIDs        []string `datastore:"cat_ids,noindex"`
    ListIDs            []string `datastore:"list_ids,noindex"`
    DefaultListIDIndex int      `datastore:"default_list_id_index,noindex"`
}

type ModelA struct {
    DateJoin          time.Time `datastore:"date_join,"`
    Name              string    `datastore:"name,"`
    OwnerSalutation   string    `datastore:"owner_salutation,noindex"`
    OwnerEmailAddress string    `datastore:"owner_email_address,"`
    LogoURL           string    `datastore:"logo_url,noindex"`
    Messages          []ModelB  `datastore:"bm,"`
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Is just a feature incompatibility between Go vs Python model definitions?

**Attempt to Decode ModelB**

Re-define `ModelA` as follows:

```
import pb "appengine_internal/datastore"
import proto "code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto"

type ModelA struct {
    DateJoin          time.Time `datastore:"date_join,"`
    Name              string    `datastore:"name,"`
    OwnerSalutation   string    `datastore:"owner_salutation,noindex"`
    OwnerEmailAddress string    `datastore:"owner_email_address,"`
    LogoURL           string    `datastore:"logo_url,noindex"`
    Messages          []ModelB  `datastore:"-"`
}

// Load is implemented for the PropertyLoaderSaver interface.

func (seller *ModelA) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) error {
  f := make(chan datastore.Property, 100)
  for p := range c {
    if p.Name == "bm" {
      var val pb.EntityProto
      err := proto.Unmarshal([]byte(p.Value.(string)), &val)
      if err != nil {
        return err
      }
      //TODO: Store result as a new ModelB
    } else {
      f <- p
    }
  }
  close(f)
  return datastore.LoadStruct(seller, f)
}
```

But I receive the following error:
`proto: required field "{Unknown}" not set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if you dig enough you'll find the answer:

First off, when defining the LocalStructuredProperty properties in Python, you need to set `keep_keys=True`

```
class ModelB(ndb.Model):
    msg_id = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    cat_ids = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    list_ids = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
    default_list_id_index = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)

class ModelA(ndb.Model):
    date_join = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    owner_salutation = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    owner_email_address = ndb.StringProperty()
    logo_url = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    ...
    messages = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(ModelB, name='bm', repeated=True, keep_keys=True)
```

A simple redefinition in my code and mapping over my entities doing a `put()` on each fixed up the representation.

Then in my Go Code:

```
type ModelB struct {
    MessageID          string   `datastore:"msg_id,noindex"`
    CategoryIDs        []string `datastore:"cat_ids,noindex"`
    ListIDs            []string `datastore:"list_ids,noindex"`
    DefaultListIDIndex int      `datastore:"default_list_id_index,noindex"`
}

type ModelA struct {
    DateJoin          time.Time `datastore:"date_join,"`
    Name              string    `datastore:"name,"`
    OwnerSalutation   string    `datastore:"owner_salutation,noindex"`
    OwnerEmailAddress string    `datastore:"owner_email_address,"`
    LogoURL           string    `datastore:"logo_url,noindex"`
    Messages          []ModelB  `datastore:"-"`
}

// Load is implemented for the PropertyLoaderSaver interface.
func (s *ModelA) Load(c <-chan datastore.Property) (err error) {
    f := make(chan datastore.Property, 32)
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    defer func() {
        if err == nil {
            err = <-errc
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer close(f)
        for p := range c {
            if p.Name == "bm" {
                var b ModelB
                err := loadLocalStructuredProperty(&b, []byte(p.Value.(string)))
                if err != nil {
                    errc <- err
                    return
                }
                s.Messages = append(s.Messages, b)
            } else {
                f <- p
            }
        }
        errc <- nil
    }()
    return datastore.LoadStruct(s, f)
}
```

I had to copy a bunch from the `appengine/datastore` package as a key function wasn't exported and to simplify the amount of code I needed to copy, I dropped support for `Reference` types. I opened a ticket on the issue tracker to see if we can get the `loadEntity` function exported: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10426

```
import (    
    "errors"    
    "time"    

    "appengine"    
    "appengine/datastore"        

    pb "appengine_internal/datastore"    
    proto "code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto"    
)    

func loadLocalStructuredProperty(dst interface{}, raw_proto []byte) error {    
    var val pb.EntityProto    
    err := proto.Unmarshal(raw_proto, &val)    
    if err != nil {    
        return err    
    }    
    return loadEntity(dst, &val)    
}

//Copied from appengine/datastore since its not exported

// loadEntity loads an EntityProto into PropertyLoadSaver or struct pointer.
func loadEntity(dst interface{}, src *pb.EntityProto) (err error) {
c := make(chan datastore.Property, 32)
 errc := make(chan error, 1)
 defer func() {
    if err == nil {
            err = <-errc
        }
    }()
    go protoToProperties(c, errc, src)
    if e, ok := dst.(datastore.PropertyLoadSaver); ok {
        return e.Load(c)
    }
    return datastore.LoadStruct(dst, c)
}

func protoToProperties(dst chan<- datastore.Property, errc chan<- error, src *pb.EntityProto) {
    defer close(dst)
    props, rawProps := src.Property, src.RawProperty
    for {
        var (
            x       *pb.Property
            noIndex bool
        )
        if len(props) > 0 {
            x, props = props[0], props[1:]
        } else if len(rawProps) > 0 {
            x, rawProps = rawProps[0], rawProps[1:]
            noIndex = true
        } else {
            break
        }

        var value interface{}
        if x.Meaning != nil && *x.Meaning == pb.Property_INDEX_VALUE {
            value = indexValue{x.Value}
        } else {
            var err error
            value, err = propValue(x.Value, x.GetMeaning())
            if err != nil {
                errc <- err
                return
            }
        }
        dst <- datastore.Property{
            Name:     x.GetName(),
            Value:    value,
            NoIndex:  noIndex,
            Multiple: x.GetMultiple(),
        }
    }
    errc <- nil
}

func fromUnixMicro(t int64) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(t/1e6, (t%1e6)*1e3)
}

// propValue returns a Go value that combines the raw PropertyValue with a
// meaning. For example, an Int64Value with GD_WHEN becomes a time.Time.
func propValue(v *pb.PropertyValue, m pb.Property_Meaning) (interface{}, error) {
    switch {
    case v.Int64Value != nil:
        if m == pb.Property_GD_WHEN {
            return fromUnixMicro(*v.Int64Value), nil
        } else {
            return *v.Int64Value, nil
        }
    case v.BooleanValue != nil:
        return *v.BooleanValue, nil
    case v.StringValue != nil:
        if m == pb.Property_BLOB {
            return []byte(*v.StringValue), nil
        } else if m == pb.Property_BLOBKEY {
            return appengine.BlobKey(*v.StringValue), nil
        } else {
            return *v.StringValue, nil
        }
    case v.DoubleValue != nil:
        return *v.DoubleValue, nil
    case v.Referencevalue != nil:
        return nil, errors.New("Not Implemented!")
    }
    return nil, nil
}

// indexValue is a Property value that is created when entities are loaded from
// an index, such as from a projection query.
//
// Such Property values do not contain all of the metadata required to be
// faithfully represented as a Go value, and are instead represented as an
// opaque indexValue. Load the properties into a concrete struct type (e.g. by
// passing a struct pointer to Iterator.Next) to reconstruct actual Go values
// of type int, string, time.Time, etc.
type indexValue struct {
    value *pb.PropertyValue
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Go datastore package doesn't support two layers of slices like that. You can have `[]ModelB`, as long as `ModelB` doesn't contain any slices. Or, you can use `ModelB` in `ModelA`, and `ModelB` can have slices in it. But you can't have both `[]ModelB` and `ModelB` has slices. See [the code](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/datastore/prop.go#231) for the error condition. Your options:

1. don't do it in Go
2. write your own datastore deserializer to handle this case - this is probably hard
3. change your python data structures to satisfy the Go requirements and rewrite your data

Comment: There's something else going on as well. In Python you can't have a repeated StructuredProperty that contains a repeated subproperty (this is the same constraint as Go).  The reason you got away with it in Python is that you used LocalStructuredProperty, which uses a very different encoding than StructuredProperty -- it stores the data as a byte string, encoded in the same way as toplevel entities are encoded. But your Go code is equivalent to using StructuredProperty. Maybe you could declare it as an array of byte-strings and decode those separately?  Because that's what's going on in Python.

Comment: I am able to switch `Messages` in `ModelA` to a `[]string` instead of `[]ModelB` but I get what I assume to be protobuffer encoded strings. I tried my best looking into how Go/python encode/decode protobuffers but part of it is beyond me. I think the concept should be simple, treat the encoded strings as a new protobuffer to decode through the normal process, but I'm not sure if enough of this process is exported for me to use and quite difficult for me to recreate. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution by someone1 works great but I have many millions of entities and didn't want to have to re-put them all (to add the keep_keys=True to the LocalStructuredProperty).

So, I created a cut-down version of `EntityProto` which removes the dependency on the key & path etc... Simply replace `pb.EntityProto` with `LocalEntityProto` and the existing python-written entities should load OK (I'm using a PropertyLoadSaver for the nested struct).

Disclaimer: I'm only using this to read from Go - I haven't tried writing the same entities back to see if they still load in Python.

```
import pb "google.golang.org/appengine/internal/datastore"
import proto "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"

type LocalEntityProto struct {
    Kind             *pb.EntityProto_Kind `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=kind,enum=appengine.EntityProto_Kind" json:"kind,omitempty"`
    KindUri          *string              `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=kind_uri" json:"kind_uri,omitempty"`
    Property         []*pb.Property       `protobuf:"bytes,14,rep,name=property" json:"property,omitempty"`
    RawProperty      []*pb.Property       `protobuf:"bytes,15,rep,name=raw_property" json:"raw_property,omitempty"`
    Rank             *int32               `protobuf:"varint,18,opt,name=rank" json:"rank,omitempty"`
    XXX_unrecognized []byte               `json:"-"`
}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) Reset()         { *m = LocalEntityProto{} }
func (m *LocalEntityProto) String() string { return proto.CompactTextString(m) }
func (*LocalEntityProto) ProtoMessage()    {}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) GetKind() pb.EntityProto_Kind {
    if m != nil && m.Kind != nil {
        return *m.Kind
    }
    return pb.EntityProto_GD_CONTACT
}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) GetKindUri() string {
    if m != nil && m.KindUri != nil {
        return *m.KindUri
    }
    return ""
}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) GetProperty() []*pb.Property {
    if m != nil {
        return m.Property
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) GetRawProperty() []*pb.Property {
    if m != nil {
        return m.RawProperty
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *LocalEntityProto) GetRank() int32 {
    if m != nil && m.Rank != nil {
        return *m.Rank
    }
    return 0
}
```