# Flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

So I have a struct like this

```
type Bus struct {
    Number          string
    Name            string
    DirectStations  []Station  // Station is another struct
    ReverseStations []Station
}
```

and I'm trying to store an instance of this to the Datastore:

```
key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Bus", bus.Number, 0, nil)
_, err := datastore.Put(c, key, &bus)
```

but I'm getting the error

```
datastore: 
flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices: 
field "DirectStations"
```

How does one solve this?

**Edit:**

Turns out you can't have a slice of struct, where that struct contains other slices.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/20710802/6309 help?

Comment: Not really. I've seen that post but I don't really get it.

Comment: The part stating that "The go datastore package doesn't support two layers of slices" is pretty clear. What to do is less clear, and involve looking into what the appengine/datastore is doing.

Comment: Could you please post here the Station struct - it seems that the error happens because it contains slices too.

Comment: Well, yes, it contains a string and another struct. That struct contains three string slices.

Comment: @AlexAtNet Seems like you're right. I can't have other slices in the Station struct.

Answer (score 3):

Just encode this struct into json (bytes) and store the json in the datastore

EDIT / UPDATE

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Bus struct {
    Number          string    `json:"number"`
    Name            string    `json:"name"`
    DirectStations  []Station `json:"directstation"` // Station is another struct
    ReverseStations []Station `json:"reversestation"`
}

type Station struct {
    StationName string `json:"stationname"` // these tag names must match exactly  how they look in json
}

func toJson(i interface{}) []byte {
    data, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return data
}
func fromJson(v []byte, vv interface{}) {
    json.Unmarshal(v, vv)

}

func main() {
    bus := Bus{}
    st := []Station{{"station1"}, {"station2"}}
    bus.DirectStations = make([]Station, len(st))
    for i, v := range st {
        bus.DirectStations[i] = v
    }
    bus.Number = "2"
    bus.Name = "BusName"
    js := toJson(bus)
    fmt.Println("JSON OUTPUT", string(js))
    bus2 := Bus{}
    fromJson(js, &bus2)
    fmt.Printf("ORIGINAL STRUCT OUTPUT %#v", bus2)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/neAGgcAIZG

Comment: I've given up on this some time ago. But, yes, I seem to remember that I've done what you suggested. It all worked well for writing the bytes in the datastore. But reading the bytes back just returned an empty sequence. I've given up on Go + Google AppEngine after trying to get around these issues unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for anyone that comes here is to just not store the slice of structures as a child in the datastore then just load them up separately when you're loading the obj

Something like:

```
type Parent struct {
  Id       int64      `json:"id"`
  Nested   []Child    `json:"children" datastore:"-"`  
  ...
}

type Child struct {
  Id       int64      `json:"id"`
  ParentId int64      `json:"parent_id"`
  ...
}
```

Then when you want to load the parent, let's assume this code is in a service module and you've got a handy data module to actually pull stuff from the datastore (which you probably should)

```
func LoadParentWithNested(parent_id int64) (Parent, error){
  parent := data.GetParent(parent_id)
  parent.Nested := data.LoadNested(parent.Id)

  return parent
}
```

Obviously you'll want error checking and all that, but this is kind of what you've got to do for complex nested structures.