# Google Datastore nested entity's in Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I having some problems with design my model ,
Because my model contains slice of a slice and  im getting an  error

```
flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices
```

What will be the best approach  to design   something like that

I prefer to change my design instead of create my own serialize  method like suggested in this post:

[Loading datastore entities from Python project in Go leads to nested structs slices of slices error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710802/loading-datastore-entities-from-python-project-in-go-leads-to-nested-structs-sli)

```
type Inner2 struct {
    Y      float64
    inner3 []Inner3
}

type Inner3 struct {
    Z bool
}

type Outer struct {
    A int16
    I []Inner2
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823186/flattening-nested-structs-leads-to-a-slice-of-slices - The approach here suggests converting your entity to and from json when storing which sounds like it could work for you. Also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710802/loading-datastore-entities-from-python-project-in-go-leads-to-nested-structs-sli - This post in it the context of python, but it's the same problem. Hope these help.

Comment: @user3508122 i saw those  posts but i prefer not  to write my own serialize method .

Comment: Checkout PropertyLoadSaver https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface maybe it can help!

Comment: In the linked question, Guido van Rossum (creator of Python) explains the cause and alternatives to the problem quite well. You're unlikely to get any better answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix for this is coming in a few days to cloud.google.com/go/datastore -- support for nested entity values!

See post here for details:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-go-announce/79jtrdeuJAg